# Possible to limit to scope/range of a lookahead

Tags: regex

We can check to see if a digit is in a password, for example, by doing something like:

```
(?=.*\d)
```

Or if there's a digit and lowercase with:

```
(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])
```

This will basically go on "until the end" to check whether there's a letter in the string.

However, I was wondering if it's possible in some sort of generic way to limit the scope of a lookahead. Here's a basic example which I'm hoping will demonstrate the point:

```
start_of_string;
middle_of_string;
end_of_string;
```

I want to use a single regular expression to match against `start_of_string` + `middle_of_string` + `end_of_string`.

Is it possible to use a lookahead/lookbehind in the `middle_of_string` section **WITHOUT KNOWING WHAT COMES BEFORE OR AFTER IT**? That is, not knowing the size or contents of the preceding/succeeding string component. And limit the scope of the lookahead to only what is contained in that portion of the string?

Let's take one example:

```
start_of_string = 'start'
middle_of_string = '123'
end_of_string = 'ABC'
```

Would it be possible to check the contents of each part but limit it's scope like this?

```
string = 'start123ABC'
# Check to make sure the first part has a letter, the second part has a number and the third part has a capital


((?=.*[a-z]).*) # limit scope to the first part only!!
((?=.*[0-9]).*) # limit scope to only the second part.
((?=.*[A-Z]).*) # limit scope to only the last part.
```

In other words, can lookaheads/lookbehinds be "chained" with other components of a regex without it screwing up the entire regex?

**UPDATE**:

Here would be an example, hopefully this is more helpful to the question:

```
START_OF_STRING = 'abc'
```

Does 'x' exist in it? `(?=.*x)` ==> `False`

```
END_OF_STRING = 'cdxoy'
```

Does 'y' exist in it? `(?=.*y)` ==> `True`

```
FULL_STRING = START_OF_STRING + END_OF_STRING
'abcdxoy'
```

Is it possible to chain the two regexes together in any sort of way to only wok on its 'substring' component?
For example, now `(?=.*x)` in the first part of the string would return True, but it should not.

```
`((?=.*x)(?=.*y)).*`
```

I think the short answer to this is "No, it's not possible.", but am looking to hear from someone who understands this to tell why it is or isn't.

Comment: Replace the dot with a character class that excludes the underscore.

Comment: I think you could also do that without a lookahead `something_[^_]+_something` using a negated character class

Comment: @Thefourthbird could you please see the updated question? I'm tried to clarify the "scoping" I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Still no idea what you mean. Could you provide a real life problem?

Comment: Perhaps you could make use of a negated character class if you know that you have for example 2 underscores and you want to make sure there is an `s` between the first and the second. https://regex101.com/r/bKud2v/1

Comment: Or this page about contrast might be helpful https://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#contrast

Comment: How do you define "middle_of_string" if you don't know the size of "start_of_string"?

Comment: @Nick `full_string = a + b + c`, where `b` is `middle_of_string`

Comment: But what defines where `a` ends and `b` starts?

Comment: @Nick `a = 'hello'
b = 'arrow'
c = 'xyz'
full_string = a + b + c` ?

Comment: My point is that if I look at the string `helloarrowxyz` I have no way of knowing which is `start`, which is `middle` and which is `end`. So that makes it impossible to "scope" a regex to only look at a specific part of the string. But if you have the string in separate parts to begin with, why not apply the conditions to each string individually?

Comment: @Nick exactly, that's the essence of the question. Is it possible to chain multiple individual regexes into one where a positive lookahead is used in one of the individual regex parts.

Comment: First of all you do not need that ever. Then, `^.{0,<LENGTH_OF_START-1>}x.{0,<LENGTH_OF_END-1>}y` could work, but if you do not know those, it has no solution. There is no solution because there is no such a problem you describe.

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 I really highly recommend that you don't do this if you're thinking about implementing it for password validation. See [Reference - Password Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48345922/3600709)

Comment: @ctwheels thanks, but it's unrelated to a password. Really I'm interested in the theory of if it's possible to chain regexes together, and what limitations there might be with that.

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 how are the substrings determined? The easiest way to do this is by applying a regex to the substring directly. Modifying the regex is also possible but a lot of unnecessary work.

Answer (score 1):

In .NET and javascript you could use a positive lookahead at the start of your string component and a negative lookbehind at the end of it to "constrain" the match. Example:

```
.*(?=.*arrow)(?<middle>.*)(?<=.*arrow).*
helloarrowxyz
{'middle': 'arrow'}
```

If in pcre, python, or other you would need to either have a fixed width lookahead to constraint it from going too far forward, such as what Wiktor Stribiżew says above:

```
.*(?=.{0,5}arrow)(?<middle>.{0,5}).*
```

Otherwise, it wouldn't be possible to do without either a fixed-width lookahead or a variable width look-behind.